# Ubuntu server and schooltool

Tags: server, software-installation, remote

I want to install schooltool on a remote webserver for trying it with some colleagues and I could not find any ubuntu free web server where to install it and isntructions on how to install it on a remote web server.  Does anyone know one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A free web server would be Apache2. You can install it by typing

> sudo apt-get install apache2

You can find a tutorial right here: [CLICK](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)
You only need the part about the apache.